# SQL SERVER 2016 OFFSET

Tags: sql, offset

Deseo realizar dos consultas la primera me debe traer los primeros 18 datos con top 18 sale. Pero la segunda me debe traer los 18 posteriores pero sql server no tiene la funcion limit y dice que la reemplaza offset pero el sql no la toma me sale "incorrect syntax near "offset""

Lo que hice fue crear un tabla temporal realizar la consulta y sacarla luego los datos con un select row_number. Pero me parece excesivo para una consulta , ademas debo llevarla al jasper y entre mas sencilla mejor.

Agradezco cualquier dato sobre una función que me ayude a sacar los siguiente "n" registro de una consulta obviando los primeros "m" de la misma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quer version de SQL Server tienes? Lo puedes revisar ejecutando lo siguiente SELECT @@VERSION

Comment: sql server 2016

Comment: hasta donde he podido documentarme el OFFSET solo funciono para  la versión 2012

Comment: Podrias poner la estructura de tus tablas y algunos datos de ejemplo para poder realizar las pruebas correspondientes, y el OFFSET no solo funciona para 2012 si no para todas las demás posteriores a el

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo posiblemente sea una versión menor a 2012 en ese caso no existe el OFFSET en ese caso te puedes apoyar del ROW_NUMBER y de unas variables para seleccionar lo que deseas te muestro como y si gustas lo puedes volver un sp y así trabajarlo saludos.

```
--Creamos la tabla de prueba llamada Customers
DECLARE @Customers TABLE (
    FirstName VARCHAR(50), 
    LastName  VARCHAR(50),
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(10),
    EmailAddress VARCHAR(50),
    CreationDate DATETIME
)
--Llenamos MIL de datos
;WITH L0 AS (SELECT 1 c FROM(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1)c(D)),
      L1 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L0 CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
      L2 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L1 CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
      L3 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L2 CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
      L4 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L3 CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
      L5 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L4 CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
      L6 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L5 CROSS JOIN L5 AS B) --SUFICIENTE PARA UN MILLON

INSERT INTO @Customers (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress, CreationDate)
SELECT TOP 1000 REPLACE(NEWID(),'-',''), REPLACE(NEWID(),'-',''), 
    CAST( CAST(ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*1000000000+4000000000,0) AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(10)),
    REPLACE(NEWID(),'-','') + '@gmail.com',     
    DATEADD(HOUR,CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 19999 as INT) + 1 ,'2006-01-01')
FROM L6

DECLARE
@InitialRow INT=0--Donde iniciara puede ser 10,20,30 etc
,@RowsRetrieve INT=10--cuantos quieres 10,20 30 es decir si mandamos 

--@InitialRow=0 y @RowsRetrieve =10 nos devolvera del 1 al 10 si mandamos 
--@InitialRow=10 y @RowsRetrieve =10 nos devolvera del 11 al 20 asi sucesivamente.

--Asigamos que sigue
DECLARE @lFirstRec INT,
@lLastRec INT,
@lTotalRows INT
SET @lFirstRec = ( @InitialRow)
SET @lLastRec = ( @InitialRow + @RowsRetrieve + 1 )
SET @lTotalRows = @lFirstRec - @lLastRec + 1

--prueba empezando del 1 al 10
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ROWNUM,* FROM @Customers)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE ROWNUM > @LFIRSTREC AND ROWNUM < @LLASTREC
```

Aqui un ejemplo aqui puedes jugar con los parametros para que veas como funciona.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8c11361399692901fe9678362bd00134